# Core audio high CPU usage when no sound playing

Tags: cocoa, core-audio, cpu-usage

I am just starting to learn Core Audio and made a simple test application the plays three different piano notes. It seems pretty good except for one small thing.

At first, the app uses about 7% or so of the CPU (visible in activity monitor), which I assume is normal because it is running a live `AUGraph`. However, as more notes are played the CPU usage keeps increasing, even though no sound may be playing at the time.

A timeline of this below:

1. Starts app. Low to none CPU usage.
2. Plays notes, medium CPU usage.
3. Notes finish & no sound playing, medium CPU usage.

The code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    NewAUGraph(&audioGraph);

    AudioComponentDescription cd;
    AUNode outputNode;
    AudioUnit outputUnit;

    cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentFlags = 0;
    cd.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;

    //AUGraphNewNode(audioGraph, &cd, 0, NULL, &outputNode);
    AUGraphAddNode(audioGraph, &cd, &outputNode);
    //AUGraphGetNodeInfo(audioGraph, outputNode, 0, 0, 0, &outputUnit);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(audioGraph, outputNode, &cd, &outputUnit);

    AUNode mixerNode;
    AudioUnit mixerUnit;

    cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentFlags = 0;
    cd.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_StereoMixer;

    AUGraphAddNode(audioGraph, &cd, &mixerNode);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(audioGraph, mixerNode, &cd, &mixerUnit);

    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(audioGraph, mixerNode, 0, outputNode, 0);

    AUGraphOpen(audioGraph);
    AUGraphInitialize(audioGraph);
    AUGraphStart(audioGraph);

    AUNode synthNode;


    cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentFlags = 0;
    cd.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DLSSynth;

    AUGraphAddNode(audioGraph, &cd, &synthNode);
    AUGraphNodeInfo(audioGraph, synthNode, &cd, &synthUnit);

    AUGraphConnectNodeInput(audioGraph, synthNode, 0, mixerNode, 0);

    AUGraphUpdate(audioGraph, NULL);
    CAShow(audioGraph);

}

- (IBAction)playMusic:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 127, 0);
    sleep(1);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 127, 0);
    sleep(1);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 127, 0);
}

- (void)one:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 127, 0);
}

- (void)two:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 127, 0);
}

- (void)three:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 127, 0);
}
```

What's going on? How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: first thought - check for busy loops. BTW - couldnt find source code in this archive - only trees and trees of directories :)

Comment: What are busy loops and how do I check for them? Hmmm... it downloads a `zip` file when I click on the link. That's all the code in the project though. The only other things are a UI, xcodeproj and such.

Comment: Does your code runs in a thread? If yes - what is the condition when you are not playing the audio. Try adding some sleeping code in there when its not playing. On the other thought - check if you close all handles correctly and stop the playback mechanism.

Comment: @spudwaffle: A busy loop is simply a loop (such as `for` or `while`) in your code, particularly one that runs for a significant amount of time, consuming CPU time and keeping you from returning to the run loop quickly.

Comment: You should use Instruments's Time Profiler instrument to profile your application and see what your application is doing in all of the CPU time it's consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out!

Basically, I was just forgetting to stop playing the notes, and although they tapered off into silence, they were still playing and making the computer work.

This can be fixed by playing the note again with velocity set to `0`. So, the code would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)playMusic:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 0, 0);
    sleep(1);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 0, 0);
    sleep(1);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 0, 0);
}

- (void)one:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 60, 0, 0);
}

- (void)two:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 62, 0, 0);
}

- (void)three:(id)sender {
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 127, 0);
    MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x90, 64, 0, 0);
}
```

I guess if I wanted the note to play longer I could wait between starting and stopping the note.

Thanks for all your help: @user757808 @Peter Hosey @mbykov

Comment: Shouldn't you actually be sending the stop message? 0x80 ?

Comment: MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(synthUnit, 0x80, 60, 127, 0);

Comment: @drewish That would make more sense! Thanks.

Comment: Both MIDI Note Off (0x80) and MIDI Note On (0x90) with a velocity of 0 are valid ways to stop a MIDI note.

Answer (score 0):

The most CPU heavy part in your code is AudioUnit processing procedure. Try set up same sample rate for hardware that is used for media played to reduce CPU loading.

```
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareSampleRate, size, &float64);
```

And there only one way to stop AudioUnit from processing - AUGraphStop.

I tried everything, quit from activity monitor, close all system sounds, only what had helped was:

1. boot with shift on (safe boot)
2. turn on iTunes

Or completely reformat the HD and reinstall Lion if you have the time.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on Mac. That only looks like it works on iOS.